# In flutter,How to design an app walkthrough using flutter_intro package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I’m new in flutter. Recently I wanted to add app walkthrough for new users in the first log in in app. After many research, I find a package called flutter_intro( https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_intro). But reading the documentation, I find it difficult to understand it properly.but I want to do exact feature in my app what flutter_intro package do. You can suggest me any other packages like this.

It would be appreciated if anyone could help me regarding this by example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [showcaseview](https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview) package which is easy to use and has very good documentation